# How to maintain a struct in which its fields will be changed or added between different platforms and versions

Tags: c, struct

I am doing embedded programming. The fields declared in the struct may be extendable or changed between different platform. Lets assume if I have the following struct to save the input data from the device:

At beginning, I have a struct to fill in data from a LG Phone device. Let's call this code **Version 1.**

```
struct GPURequest{
    int                 deviceID;
    StreamInfo          inputInfo; //StreamInfo is another pre-defined struct
}
```

Later in future, I will need to support the Samsung Pad. The new platform will provide more info to fill the **GPURequest** struct, the struct will be different and look as following, let's **version 2**:

```c
struct GPURequest{
    unsigned int        deviceID;
    StreamInfo          inputInfo;  //StreamInfo is another pre-defined struct
    unsigned int        frames;     //a new introduced field
    RegionInfo          regionINfo; //RegionInfo is a new introduced struct that is unique to Samsung Pad
}
```

Here is my problem: If I create a new *GPURequest* struct for every new platform I am going to support, the struct  will be growing too large and have lots of similar duplicated code that won't be used by other platforms. I want to maintain just one basic struct and find a smart and flexible solution to add new field members or change the existing field types based different platform input, so that my code can be used across multiple platforms without redundant code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll want to add a format identifier, plus possibly a "length" field (`uint16_t`?) to indicate how long the header is.

Comment: the preprocessor is what you want - #ifdef PLATFORM1 ... #idef PLATFORM2 ...

Comment: you could add a platform specific discriminator field to indicate the platform id, like an enum with values for Windows, Linux, etc. And then store the platform specific fields in a union.

Comment: Slap on a EX and call it a day

Comment: @bruceg, I am not sure I understand you meant by storing the platform-specific fields in a union. Let's say both LG and Samsung have 1 common field.  However, LG has 2 specific fields, called LG_A and LG_B;  Samsung has 3 specific fields called SM_A,SM_B and SM_C. Do you suggest put all these two devices' fields into one union?

Comment: @tadman, would you please elaborate the what is the intention add a length field to indicate the length the of header file?

Comment: I mean you could have a member in your struct called platformSpecific p;  Where `platformSpecific` is a union of the LG and Samsung structs.  So, platformSpecific looks like this: ```typedef union platformSpecific {
   LGStruct LG;
   SamsungStruct Samsung;
} platformSpecific;
```

Comment: @bruceg, thanks. Let's say the following struct:``` struct request{ union platformSpecific p}```.  But assuming SamsungStruct occupies memory size  2 times larger than LGStruct. When the following struct is used on LG, will memory allocation become a too much waste because Samsung struct is 2 times larger?

Comment: A `union` is as large as its largest member automatically. Length fields are super rudimentary, so look at low level protocol examples, even the UDP RFC, for how they play out.

Comment: If the unions are too large, you could have the union members be pointers, but them memory allocation and freeing becomes more complex

Comment: @tadman, I have got what you imply here. the fields will be declared for different platforms. e.g LG may have 3 fields, but Samsung may have 10 fields, and Mi phone may have 22 fields. how this length field can help to construct the  GPURequest struct?

Comment: If you want to store variable length fields in a structure you need to serialize and deserialize it usually helps to store the length (in octets) to ease decoding. Your 22 field version may be 88 bytes or more, so state that in your structure.